# Not able to pass the values to Handlebars registerHelpers

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is my template,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >  
    Welcome {{name}}, <a href="#">Click here to {{checkStatus status}}</a>
</script>
```

My app.js,

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return {
        name: "jack",
        status: "leaving"
    };
}
});
```

I have a Handlebars registerHelper,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( "checkStatus", function ( status ){ 
    if (status == "leaving" )
    {
        return 'leave';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'stay'; 
    }
});
```

But my out put is,

```
Welcome jack, Click here to stay
```

I am not sure why the registerHelper always returns "stay". 
My expected output is,

```
Welcome jack, Click here to leave
```

Given the link to jsbin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tekoli/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
Welcome {{name}}, <a href="#">Click here to {{checkStatus status=status}}</a>
```

and

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( "checkStatus", function ( ){ 
  if (this.get('status') == "leaving" )
  {
      return 'leave';
  }
  else
  {
      return 'stay';
  }
});
```

which seams to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, registerHelper `checkStatus` takes the next parameter as a string. Since you're passing `"status"` it always takes the `else` condition.

If you can put those objects in an array, then you can do the following:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{CheckStatus item.status}}
{{/each}}
```

---

EDIT:
After some research about this topic, i found a solution which i would like to add upon here.

There is a `Ember.registerBoundHelper` which passes all the relevant data as a final argument to the function.

Please update your Register helper as:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper( "checkStatus", function ( status ){ 
if (status == "leaving" )
{
    return 'leave';
}
else
{
    return 'stay';
}
});
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. I tried it already, but the value passed to registerHelper is "item.status" and not the value. If its working for you can you share a demo in jsbin.